# Please help I am confused to decide which statistical test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a data set, have two interval variables and lots of categorical (ordinal and nominal) sociodemographic variables. 
Lets say one of may interval variable is $x$ and the other is $y$, I want to test  effect of $x$ and a demographic variable such as gender or educational level on $y$. In other words, how can I compare or find a relationship of $x$ scores with different educational levels and $y$ scores (dependent variable)? I want to say that there is a difference between $x$ scores from high school and $y$ scores. Or I want to say that there is a relationship between $x$ scores from high school and $y$ scores. Or I want to say that x scores from university educational level is related to y scores.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to see if the continuous variable $Y$ is different across levels of some factors $F_1$, $F_2$ while controlling for the values of the continue variable $X$ then you need [ANCOVA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_covariance).

A sample R code for the above scenario would be

```
X = c(65, 65, 60, 70, 55, 80, 40, 90, 50, 100, 30, 95)
F1 = as.factor(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))
F2 = as.factor(c(3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4))
Y = c(29, 28, 22, 19, 18, 28, 16, 25, 17, 35, 15, 32)
ancova.df = data.frame(X, F1, F2, Y)
library(car)
Anova(lm(Y ~ X + F1 + F2, ancova.df))
```

If you want to provide also a prediction for $Y$ in terms of $X$ and the factors $F_1$, $F_2$, ..., $F_k$ then regression is the answer. If a factor is nominal or ordinal with 2 values then use it as is. If a factor has more than two values then create the corresponding [dummy variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29) and use that new variables in the linear model instead of the original variable.

Hope the above will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Regression certainly seems like the place to start. It also sounds like you  want to do some stratified analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You have one continuous response variable (Y) and and two  or more inputs (X and gender/ educational level).

You can use multiple regression using dummy variables.

https://www.researchgate.net/post/how_can_I_run_dummy_variable_regression_model_for_January_effect_is_there_any_guide_on_how_to_use_it

may be useful.